# Get values of inputs with same name

Tags: php

Ok, I have a task to write a simple php ticket system. I can't work out how to get all values from input called ages

My code looks like this and I don't really know where to go from here

```
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="number">Ticket count </label>
            <input type="number" name="number" />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Set ages" class="submit"/>

            <?php
                $numberOfTickets = $_POST['number'];
                for($i=1;$i <=$numberOfTickets;$i++){
                    echo "<select class='ages' name='ages'>";
                    echo "<option value='adult'>18 år och uppåt</option>";
                    echo "<option value='youth'>13 – 18 år</option>";
                    echo "<option value='child'>7 – 12 år</option>";
                    echo "<option value='baby'>under 7  år</option>";
                    echo "</select>";
                }
            ?>

        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Beställ biljett" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div><!--content-->
    <?php
        class Ticket
        {           
          public function price($age)
          {
            return $price;
          }
          public function ages($ages)
          {
                foreach($ages as $f)
                {
                    echo "$f</br>";
                }
          }

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the <select> is inside a loop, I assume there are more than one select named "ages". If that is the case, do this:

```
echo "<select class='ages' name='ages[]'>";
```

And to get the values in PHP, use this:

```
$_POST['ages']
```

That will be an array. Use for, foreach, implode or whatever you need to convert the arrays back to text.

Please explain more if this is not what you meant.